# How to Parse Collection in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a IEnumerable Collection of Custom DataType that I'm sending to the Client.
I want to parse the collection in my JQuery method. Currently I'm getting value as "undefined". Below is my code:

Service:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
 IEnumerable<CustomData> GetSetting(long userId);

  public IEnumerable<CustomData> GetSetting(long userId)
  {
        var tempData = Context.DialogSettings.Where(item => item.id == userId).ToList();
        return tempData.Select(dialogSetting => new CustomData { KeyName = dialogSetting.KeyName, KeyValue = dialogSetting.KeyValue }).ToList();
  }


[DataContract]
public class CustomData
{
   [DataMember]
   public String KeyName;
   [DataMember]
   public String KeyValue;
 }
```

Client:

```
function LoadSetting() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "SampleService.svc/GetSetting",
                    data: '{"userId": "' + 1 + '"}',
                    processData: true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var myHistoryList = data.d;
                        alert(myHistoryList); // here I'm getting value: undefined
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried `alert(data)`?

Comment: Further to what thg435 said, wouldn't you expect `data` to be an array of objects if you're sending a collection/list? Is `data.length` also undefined in your ajax success callback?

Comment: Why would `data` have a `d` var, if it's a list???

Comment: I tried with alert(data) and getting the 4 items like [object Object] (4 because the method GetSetting() return 4 items to the client) but I don't know how to parse the [object Object] at the client side.

Comment: ok, when you type "your.host/SampleService.svc/GetSetting?userId=1" in your browser, what do you get?

Answer (score 2):

From the comments on the question I can safely presume that the following js code will work:

```
if(typeof data != 'undefined'){
    alert(data[0].KeyName); //this will yield a value.
}
else
    alert('Ok. This is weird');
```

Comment: thanks. your solution works when returning IEnumerable<Object> through api 2 controller